# Populate html table using jquery ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm stuck here for about 4 hours do alot of research and cannot fin the answer.
I want to repopulate the table after updating the contents using jquery ajax and php so here is my code.

PHP script:

```
    if(isset($_POST['myinputval']))
    {

        $uinput = $_POST['myinputval'];
        $uinput = $mysqli->real_escape_string($uinput);


        $query = ('INSERT INTO tbltest values (" ","'.$uinput.'") ');

        if($mysqli->query($query))
        {

        } else 
            echo 'fail'. $mysqli->error;
        }

        $result= $mysqli->query("Select *from tbltest");

        if($result->num_rows>0)
        {
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $sendtojq[]=$row;
            }

            echo json_encode($sendtojq);
        }

        mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Here is my script

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxsubmit()
        {
            var myinputval = $("#input1").val();

            $.ajax({url:'myphp.php', type:'post', data:{
                myinputval:myinputval
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        }


        </script>
```

This is the output when submitted

```
[{"ID":"1","NAME":".$newinput."},{"ID":"2","NAME":".$newinput."},{"ID":"3","NAME":".$newinput."},{"ID":"4","NAME":".$newinput."},{"ID":"5","NAME":".$newinput."},{"ID":"6","NAME":".$newinput."},{"ID":"7","NAME":"$newinput"},{"ID":"8","NAME":"twst"},{"ID":"9","NAME":"twst"},{"ID":"10","NAME":"testtt"},{"ID":"11","NAME":"testtt"},{"ID":"12","NAME":"thisssss"},{"ID":"13","NAME":"thisssss"},{"ID":"14","NAME":"tstet"},{"ID":"15","NAME":"Last"},{"ID":"16","NAME":""},{"ID":"17","NAME":"dddddddd"},{"ID":"18","NAME":"aaaaaaaaaaa"},{"ID":"19","NAME":"gggggggggggggggggggggg"},
```

Now what I want to do is get every single element of the array which is stored in the variable 'data' and use is at as the value of my table. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Refer this: http://jsfiddle.net/opyj2z5o/

Comment: What did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: I tried using this, 
  var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  alert(parsedData[1]);

 
});
}

Comment: but the output is just object Object

Comment: @RayonDabre I saw your fiddle, but will that gonna be static? I need to make a dynamic table, which will be updated everytime I make an update

Comment: parsedData[1] will have one rows data alert(parsedData[1][0]);.you should do console.log(parsedData[1]) and see data.

Comment: done it 3 time and i Always get the same output Object {ID: "2", NAME: ".$newinput."}
(index):36 Object {ID: "2", NAME: ".$newinput."}
(index):36 Object {ID: "2", NAME: ".$newinput."}

Comment: @JakeBalba, You must be kidding. Just use that example in your ajax `success` callback..

Comment: my problem is I dont know how to manipulate that JSON 'data', been searching for hours now for that, any links you can give? Thanks

Comment: Dear @JakeBalba, Refer this: http://jsfiddle.net/opyj2z5o/1/